# Network Adapter not detected

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless

I have an Asus laptop with dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04.  Fast boot is disabled on Windows.

Wifi had been working with no problems on both operating systems.  But now all of sudden, it's gone on both.

On Ubuntu, the output of `lspci` is

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Host Controller (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9da8 (rev 30)
00:1e.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9daa (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series (rev 03)
```

On Windows, it does not detect any networking hardware.  Windows Network Properties says:

```
Name: Wi-Fi
Description: Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
Status: Not Present
Connectivity (IPv4/IPv6): Disconnected
```

How can I get the wifi back to work?

Comment: Gone on both means it's neither's problem. Check uEFI settings (if applicable), re-seat the card (if applicable) or replace it (if possible) or use an USB one.

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed the notebook doesn’t have a hardware switch to enable/disable the wireless card? 

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing.  And after checking, I couldn't find any hardware switch.